# use of superlatives

Tags: grammar

What would be correct: Youngest and oldest soldier cut the cake or youngest and oldest soldiers cut the cake, knowing that we are referring to only one youngest and one oldest?

Comment: Probly it's best to use _the_ before both _youngest_ and _oldest_; the definite article is part of the superlative construction. As to  whether to use singular or plural for _soldier_, and whether to delete the first _soldier_, as in the examples here, it's speaker's choice. Singular or plural both work; it's one event, with two participants.

Answer (score 2):

Either is possible, but I think *soldiers* is preferable.

Either way, you need *the*:

> The youngest and the oldest soldiers cut the cake.

Both choices are possibly ambiguous: *soldiers* doesn't make it completely clear that there are exactly two; whereas *soldier* might in principle mean one single person who was both extremes (though in the real world that can't happen if there is more than one soldier).

Comment: And if there is only one soldier, he clearly cuts the cake.